# Moving files based on a source path found in a table using SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I've chased my tail for a full 12 hours. Haven't found the right solution.
I'm locked into using SSIS. I have a SQL Server table with full paths and filenames already concatenated. Examples:

```
\\MydevServer1\C$\ABC\App_Data\Sample.pdf
\\MydevServer2\E$\Garth\App_Data\Morefiles.txt
\\MydevServer3\D$\Paths\App_Data\MySS.xlsx
```

etc.

I need to read each row of the table, get the path and filename and move that file to a new static destination directory.

The rows in the table will remain unchanged. I only use it as a source to locate the file to be moved.

I've tried:

1) Feeding a resultset from an ole db source to a recordset destination then to an Object variable that connects via variable to a foreach loop container holding a files system task. (Very problematic.)

2) Sending the table rows to a .csv file and reading each line of the csv file using a foreach loop container holding a file system task.

3) Reading directly from the table rows using a foreach loop container holding a file system task. (preferred).

and many other scenarios.

I have viewed a hundred examples online, but most of them involve loading a table, or sending results to flat files, or moving files from one folder to another based on extension type, etc. I haven't found anything on configuring a file system task to read a table supplied path and move the file based on the table value as the source.

I'm rambling. :-)
Any insight or help will be appreciated. I'm not new to SSIS, but I sure feel like it right now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create two string variables to store source and destination paths
2. Use an Execute SQL Task to populate a Full Recordset (Variable with Object data type)
3. Use For Loop container to go through each row of recordset and set those two variables.
4. Inside For Loop container, use File System Task. You need to specify IsSourcePathVariable = True, IsDestinationPathVariable = True, path variables - DestinationVariable / SourceVariable, and set operation (copy, move, etc.)

Comment: I think the problem I'm having is trying to set the Object variable to a string variable in the Foreach loop.
Under variable mappings in the foreach loop I reference a string variable. I thought this would map the Object variable from the recordset to a string. I then use this string as the Sourcepath variable.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I've been tail chasing due to the error, "Source is empty error".
This was caused by a blank first row in my recordset. I was searching for a fix to the Object variable is empty issue, when in reality the issue was that the Object variable couldn't find data right off the bat.

Insert shameful smug here.
Thanks to Anton for the help.